# Is there a sequence of positive integers such that $a_{n+3}-a_{n+2}=\sqrt{a_{n+1}+a_n}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recurrence-relations

Can anyone give me a hint on this?

Is there a sequence of positive integers such that $(a_{n+3}-a_{n+2})^2=a_{n+1}+a_n$ for all $n$?
Or strongly, $a_{n+3}-a_{n+2}=\sqrt{a_{n+1}+a_n}$.

If there is, how can I find it?

If there is not, how can I prove it?

About the erased comment and to prevent misunderstandings: The sequence $a_n=0$ for all $n$ does not work since $0$ is not positive.

Comment: $0$ is not positive.

Comment: $1,3,1,3,1,3,1,3\dots$

Comment: Oh, thanks. I didn't see that manipulating it like I did would crate new solutions. So I have just edited the question.

Comment: but $1-3 \neq \sqrt{1+3}$ isn't it?

Comment: @SiongthyeGoh The question has changed since I put up that comment. Clear questions that change when people put up answers are tiresome. It would be better if the OP put up a new separate question.

Comment: @almagest Ury did warn that he edited the question. If he wrote another one, people would probably whinge about a duplicate. Also, the newly worded question still poses the old one's problem, but it also poses an additional (very similar) problem with a stronger condition. As my answer shows, the stronger condition makes it impossible, and your comment shows the weaker condition makes it possible - but then the question is, are there more apart from $x,y,x,y,\ldots$ where $$y={2x+1\pm\sqrt{8b+1}\over2}$$ (e.g. $3,6,3,6,\ldots$)? Are they all periodic? (This is starting to get interesting.)

Comment: Of course! All solutions with period $2$ use two consecutive triangular numbers.

Comment: Solutions with periods $3$ and $4$ looks interesting (if they exist): they can be reversed (if $x,y,z,w,x,y,z,w,\ldots$ is a solution, then so is $w,z,y,x,w,z,y,x,\ldots$).

Comment: @almagest thanks. sorry, I didn't realize that.

Comment: Why or how did this become off-topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I haven't made a mistake somewhere on the way, but here it goes for stronger condition:

Every two consecutive numbers must add up to a square, so let's call $b_n^2=a_n+a_{n+1}$. Then we get $a_4=a_3+b_1$, $a_5=a_4+b_2$, $a_{n+1}=a_n+b_{n-2}$, so
$$a_m=a_3+b_1+b_2+\ldots+b_{m-3}$$
$$b_{n+3}^2-b_{n+2}^2=a_{n+4}-a_{n+2}=b_{n+1}+b_n$$
Now let's explore the sequence $(b_n)$ a bit more:
$$b_{n+3}^2-b_{n+2}^2=b_{n+1}+b_n$$
$$b_{n+1}+b_n=(b_{n+3}+b_{n+2})(b_{n+3}-b_{n+2})=(b_{n+5}+b_{n+4})(b_{n+5}-b_{n+4})(b_{n+3}-b_{n+2})$$
and so
$$b_2+b_1=(b_4-b_3)(b_6-b_5)(b_8-b_7)\ldots(b_{2n}-b_{2n-1})(b_{2n}+b_{2n-1})$$
$$b_3+b_2=(b_5-b_4)(b_7-b_6)(b_9-b_8)\ldots(b_{2n+1}-b_{2n})(b_{2n+1}+b_{2n})$$
for an arbitrarily large $n$.

In order for that to work, all but finitely many of $b_{n+1}-b_n$ should be $1$, so for all $n\geq N$ it holds: $b_{n+1}=b_n+1$. Let $c=b_N$, then $b_{N+m}=c+m$. So for all m
$$(c+m+3)^2-(c+m+2)^2=(c+m+1)+(c+m)$$
$$2c+2m+5=2c+2m+1$$
The contradiction comes from the assumption that the sequence $(a_n)$ exists, so it doesn't.

Comment: +1 Looks good. At the moment I cannot see any solutions with period $>2$.

Comment: That was really interesting. Thanks.